# always json response parse error with cakephp

Tags: php, jquery, json, cakephp

i'am always getting a json response parse error with cakephp.
the json syntax is correct - validated with http://www.jslint.com/

```
responseText: ﻿{"success":1,"reload":0}
status: 200
```

response header:

    `Cache-Control   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
    Connection  Keep-Alive
    Content-Length  30
    Content-Type    application/json; charset=UTF-8
    Date    Thu, 20 Mar 2014 10:46:24 GMT
    Expires Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
    Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=100
    Last-Modified   Thu, 20 Mar 2014 10:46:24 GMT
    Server  Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.5.6
    X-Powered-By    PHP/5.5.6`

please help me - i dont find the error.

Answer (score 0):

did you added the content header before json creation

header('Content-Type: application/json');

Answer (score 0):

Cakephp should do this ?!?

Controller:
    $this->autoRender = false; 
    $this->request->onlyAllow('ajax'); 
    $response = array('success' => 0);
    $response['reload'] = 0;
    ....
    return json_encode($response);

jslint says JSON response is ok: ﻿[code]{"success":1,"reload":0}[/code]

jquery:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: '<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('action' => 'sortfields')); ?>',
dataType: 'json',
data: JSON.stringify(mydata),
success: function(response) {
        .....
},

error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(jqXHR);
    console.log('responseText: ' + jqXHR.responseText);
    console.log(textStatus);
    console.log(errorThrown);
}
})
```

firebug message:

```
status=200 OK
responseText: ﻿{"success":1,"reload":0}
parsererror
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character
return a.JSON.parse(b + "");
```